# Reading a file when logged in as another user

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal

I have an issue with the following:
I use the following command su -l alice then enter her password. Then I am asked to read the /root/token.txt file.

I have tried the cmd "cat /root/token.txt" without the " but receive the following error:

cat: /root/token.txt: Permission denied

Any help would be very much appreciated and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The home directory for root is locked down for obvious reasons.

If you look at it you will see only the root user can access it.

Similar to my own...

```
drwx------ 17 root root 4096 Aug 20 20:41 /root
```

Those permissions mean root has read, write & execute, but those in the root group and all others have no rights whatsoever.

Either access as root, or move it to some other directory whilst ensuring the permissions on the file itself are permissive enough.